# WP 8.1 backward compatability to WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have started working on WP 8.1 lately. There was VS Express 2012 exclusively for WP8. I have installed VS Express 2013 for Windows.

My question is, if I develop for WP 8.1 does it work for WP8 too? There are a lot of changes in WP 8.1. Please guide me in this,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use features which target 8.1, they won't work on 8.0. If 8.0 is of such importance you need to build both versions and verify that they work.

Frankly since most windows phone users can easily and cheaply upgrade their phone, if not OS to 8.1, I would only program for version 8.1 and not concern myself with a legacy market which is only getting smaller every day.